# stubbing void methods with Spock

Tags: groovy, spock

I want to use Spock to create a stub for the following interface

```
public interface LocaleResolver {
    Locale resolveLocale(HttpServletRequest request)

    void setLocale(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Locale locale)    
}
```

I can stub out the `resolveLocale` method like so

```
LocaleResolver stubLocaleResolver = Stub(LocaleResolver)
stubLocaleResolver.resolveLocale(_) >> Locale.UK
```

But I'm not sure how to stub `setLocale`. The stub should simply ignore any calls to this method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have to do anything as Spock mocks are lenient.

Comment: Does this apply to stubs as well as mocks, i.e. if you don't explicitly stub a method it will return null, 0, etc?

Comment: I use "Spock mock" as an overarching term, so yes. `Stub`s will return different values than `Mock`s (see docs), but for a `void` method this won't matter.